# How to allow cross origin in quorum?

Tags: quorum

i set up a quorum network following this tuotorial:

[Quorum](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum)

Problem is after ran this command geth attach ipc:qdata/dd1/geth.ipc when i tried to run my dapp on top of this network.It was showing me an error message: problem facing your acccount....

"http://127.0.0.1:22000 not allow cross origin..."

I know how to run  --rpccorsdomain on etheruem. But in this case i cannot able to do that

Comment: try the `--cors`. From this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51463666/6641693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quorum client is no different from geth, this page covers the options: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options